# Получаю корректный JSON только со второго раза

Tags: javascript, react-native

Доброго времени суток.

Есть web сервис который по корректным запросам отдает json.
Проблема в следующем при событии onPress на кнопке я получаю json только после 2го нажатия.
Помогите исправить

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';

import { 
  Container, 
  Content, 
  Form, 
  Item,
  Label, 
  Input,
  Button,
  Text
} from 'native-base';

//include API
import apiUtils from './tools/apiUtils';

export default class Montag extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            login: '',
            password: '',
            data: []
        }
    }

    getItems(){
        let url = `http://192.168.1.48:8888/index2.php?login=${this.state.login}&password=${this.state.password}`;

        return fetch(url,{
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          })
          .then(apiUtils.checkStatus)
          .then( (response) => response.json())
          .then( (responseJson) => { 
            this.state.data = responseJson;
          })
          .catch(e => { console.log(e)});
    }

    press(){
        this.getItems(this.state.login,this.state.password);
        console.log("data");
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <Form>
                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Label>Username</Label>
                            <Input onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({login:text}) } />
                        </Item>
                        <Item floatingLabel last>
                            <Label>Password</Label>
                            <Input onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({password:text}) } />
                        </Item>
                        <Button success block onPress={() => this.press()}>
                          <Text>Войти</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }  
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Montag', () => Montag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Помог себе сам)
Проблема была в том что я выводил результат в функции press и this.state.data не успевал принять новое значение.
Если выводить результат в

```
.then( (responseJson) => { this.state.data = responseJson;сonsole.log(this.state.data);})
```

то все в порядке